# Strange login screen freeze after trying to make changes to xkb

Tags: login, chromebook, xkb

I've been using my chromebook with Ubuntu 21.04 for a few days with no incident. Now, it freezes when I attempt to log in. The only probable cause I can identify is what I was doing immediately before, which was a (probably misguided attempt) to follow the instructions in [this](https://github.com/optio50/ChromeBook-Keyboard-xkb) readme to get a proper Chromebook keyboard layout. Given that the latest commit is 4 years old, I should have expected it wouldn't work...

To be clear, I followed the commands exactly: went into etc/X11 and renamed xkb to old_xkb, then put the provided folder in its place. When I rebooted, it froze on login.

Now, whenever I try to log in on Weyland, the mouse snaps back to the bottom right of the screen (its default position when the GUI starts) and everything freezes for upwards of a minute. Then... The screen flips upside down and is no longer frozen. Sure enough, I can try to login again... and after a long freeze, the screen flips back right-side up. I can log in with Xorg with partial functionality.

I got rid of the new xkb folder and put the old one back in its place, but that didn't solve it. Relatedly, that folder (/etc/X11/xkb) is empty.

The specific way the screen freezes and flips upside down feels like some kind of prank, and  I have no idea how it could be related to messing with xkb, especially since it occurs when logging in with Weyland, which I now understand doesn't have much to do with the X11 files.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding what the cause was - and it was indeed a stupid oversight on my part that had nothing to do with xkb, as should have been obvious to me tbh. Much earlier, I had installed the [Touchpad Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/131/touchpad-indicator/?c=112049) extension. It appeared to work, but made logging in on Wayland impossible (and indeed, it seems like a few other people reported similar problems, if only I'd bothered to look more than a couple comments down on the page). I could swear I restarted at least once before with the extension installed, but oh well. So, solved.